# How do I use extended regular expression grouping in groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy

I have this `sed` command that can pull a number from an HTML report on code coverage from Coverlet:

```
sed -rn 's/(<tr><th>Branch coverage:<\/th><td>([0-9]+.?[0-9]+)%<\/td><\/tr>)+/\2/p' /output/report/index.htm
```

When I try it in groovy it fails on the `\2` with

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/private/tmp/coverage.groovy: 19: Unexpected input: '\'; Expecting <EOF> @ line 19, column 81.
   0-9]+.?[0-9]+)%<\/td><\/tr>)+/\2/
```

This is the groovy code failing:

```
def regex = /(<tr><th>Branch coverage:<\/th><td>([0-9]+.?[0-9]+)%<\/td><\/tr>)+/\2/

new File('/tmp/output/report/index.htm').eachLine { line ->
    if ((match = line =~ regex)) {
        println match
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to escape it I guess?

Comment: You should separate the pattern from replacement.In Groovy, you just need no replacement. Get Group 2 directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed -rn 's/(<tr><th>Branch coverage:<\/th><td>([0-9]+.?[0-9]+)%<\/td><\/tr>)+/\2/p' /output/report/index.htm` contains a *substitution*  command with `-n` option and `p` flag that are both used to *extract* a certain value from a line using `sed`.

In Groovy, you should use *extracting* `.find()` method directly and grab any group you need from the match result. Here is a demo:

```
String line = '<tr><th>Branch coverage:</th><td>15.50%</td></tr>'
def m = line =~ /(<tr><th>Branch coverage:<\/th><td>([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)%<\/td><\/tr>)+/
if(m.find()) {         // If the first match is found
    println m[0][2]    // Show Group 2 value of the first match
} else {
    println 'No match' // Else, print No match
}
```

See a [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/Giu48o) printing `15.50` as a result.